# Run code after CSS transition has finished with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to wrap my head around transitionend events but I can't get them to work.

Essentially what I want to do is to run `content.style.maxHeight = 100%` after a transition has finished.

The two problems that I have run into are:

1. The code will run on both the if and else statement.
2. Doesn't work on more than the first class named: `.aboutCollapsible`

**CSS Class:**

```css
.aboutCollapsible {
    font: 16px/24px "Roboto";
    background: #202020;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 580px;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 1px 20px 5px 20px;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```js
// Collapsible
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
const el = document.querySelector(".aboutCollapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling
        if (content.style.maxHeight) {
            content.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
            content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
            el.addEventListener("transitionend", function () {
                content.style.maxHeight = "100%";
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't run your code but just by reading it I could have some clues for you.

1.The code will run on both the if and else statement.

You should try something like

```
if (content.style.maxHeight == '100%')
```

2.Doesn't work on more than the first class named: `.aboutCollapsible`

You should use

```
const el = document.querySelectorAll(".aboutCollapsible");
```

instead of just the simple querySelector that only returns the [first element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector). And then loop on the result.

Comment: I am going to mark your answer as acceptable as it solved the main problem. However, the `const el = document.querySelectorAll(".aboutCollapsible");` doesn't work with the `addEventListener` as far as I can see.

Comment: you have to do a loop on the querySelectorAll() to addEventListener to each item